# LINQ to XML basic codes

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

developers !!

I'm studying LINQ to XML with "C# in a Nutshell".
I'd like to grab two lines from the XML file.

```
When I find myself in times of trouble
Mother Mary comes to me
```

The file is like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xliff xmlns:sdl="http://sdl.com/FileTypes/SdlXliff/1.0">
  <file datatype="x-sdlfilterframework2">
    <header>
        <reference></reference>
    </header>
    <body>
        <trans-unit translate="no" id="20873339caf8">
            <source><x id="0"/></source>
        </trans-unit>
        <group>
            <sdl:cxts><sdl:cxt id="1"/></sdl:cxts>
            <trans-unit id="fb3052898e68">
                <source>When I find myself in times of trouble</source>
            </trans-unit>
        </group>
        <group>
            <sdl:cxts><sdl:cxt id="1"/></sdl:cxts>
            <trans-unit id="f3e2e9ca583c">
                <source>Mother Mary comes to me</source>
            </trans-unit>
        </group>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

Actually, I have tried ALL kinds of code I could do with the book.
But, I have failed and am in the desperate state.
Please help.

(There come some more lines. As song goes. The pattern is very strict. It comes with group, group and group elements.)

Regards

(EDIT)
My first try is like this.
I have to practice with the name of elements.
so..

```
XElement ALL = XElement.Load( myPATH );
string RSLT = "";
int CNT = 0;
foreach( XElement x in ALL.Elements() )
{
  CNT ++;
  RSLT += CNT + ".  " + x.Name + "\n";
  }
MessageBox.Show( RSLT );
```

It gives me just "1. file".
I was expecting "file header body trans-unit group..".

Comment: how do you write the file?

Comment: @M.Schena Hi. It comes from some program. Translation program name "SDL Trados Studio". The format is sdlxliff. I've tried to use "Parse" command. But, I have failed to make it a string. It is very strange file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
foreach(var srcElem in doc.Descendants("source").Skip(1))
{
    Console.WriteLine((string)srcElem);
}
```

Comment: This is nice. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("filename.xml");
string[] lines = doc.Descendants("body")
                    .Elements("group")
                    .Elements("trans-unit")
                    .Elements("source")
                    .Select(e => (string)e).ToArray();
```